# How do I find what percent of my points come from which tags?

Tags: support, tags, reputation, participation

If I assume that for an answer that I give to a question, the tags take equal shares of the points I have been voted, how do I make a ranked list of tags that gives tag name, tag rank, and sum of partial points owned by the tag?

I'm assuming there is a query for the data, but I am not sure how to do something like this.

Comment: Something like that? https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/22452/engrstudent?tab=tags

Comment: Each tag gets *all* the points of any of your (non-wiki) answers it's in. The total points that accrue to your tags will exceed your total reputation.

Comment: @Glen_b - I was meaning equal fraction.  If the answer is 10 points, and has 5 tags, each tag should get 2 points.

Comment: That's not how it works, though, @EngrStudent. And the query I wrote below doesn't calculate percentages like that either.

Comment: I think that I can munge the two.  Now if only my "tags" page was downloadable as csv.  I'm going to poke around the data explorer to see what is there.

Comment: @EngrStudent I think I must have misunderstood. You're not actually asking about points that tags accrue as shown on your profile, but about constructing a new calculation that actually works differently to the present calculation ... right?

Comment: @Glen_b - Neither the tags page, nor the query, fully answers my question.  Together, however, they do have the means to get to the answer.  I was looking for a 3-column table with headers: (tag name, tag rank, and sum of partial points).  I get name and rank from the tag page.  I get the way to get an approximation to partial points using the query results.

Comment: But how is the rank to be computed -- if it's based on the partial points it won't necessarily be in the same order as what's on the profile page. (e.g. if one tag nearly always occurs alone, it will have almost the same partial points as it does on the profile page, but if another tag nearly always occurs with 3 other tags it will have about a quarter of the partial points as it does on the profile -- so some tags might shift quite dramatically from the profile page order to an order based on a different calculation.

Comment: @Glen_b - this speaks to the follow-on of this question.  I may only be 5% on CV, but perhaps I am in the top 1% of <insert tag here>.  I know that the 5% doesn't mean a whole lot.  The rock-stars here have 144k points to my ~4k and many are PhD's in stats.  I'm pretty good at my strengths, so in while in total point-sum I might not be too great, but in point-sum by tag I might be pretty decent.  My next step is to look at that.

Comment: @EngrStudent Your most active tag seems to be [machine-learning]. You can look at the top users in this tag here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/machine-learning/topusers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm reading your question wrong, [amoeba's comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4757/how-do-i-find-what-percent-of-my-points-come-from-which-tags#comment13303_4757) pretty much answers it:

> Something like that? https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/22452/engrstudent?tab=tags

The only thing left there would be actually converting that into percentages. [I wrote a query for that](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/660948/percentage-of-users-total-rep-coming-from-each-tag?UserId=22452). Note that, [as Glen_b puts it](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4757/how-do-i-find-what-percent-of-my-points-come-from-which-tags#comment13304_4757):

> Each tag gets *all* the points of any of your (non-wiki) answers it's in. The total points that accrue to your tags will exceed your total reputation.

Which means that percentages are gonna exceed 100%, and total rep is gonna exceed the actual rep (as explained in the query's description).

One final note: my SQL-fu is not at ninja level, so let me know if you spot something completely off in the query or numbers it generates.

Comment: That is a very nice query!  This is quite useful to me.  Stackexchange and cross-validated are part of my "nerd cred" and I like to say I may only be in the top 5% of contributors, but for machine learning I am in the to xyz%.  Thank you.